# jQuery Frame Breaker by Array of Domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame

Using jQuery and an array of domains, I would like to create a frame breaker. I'd like to evaluate the top frame domain and if it's one of the domains in the array, then break it.

```
var domains = ["zoot.li", "domain.com"];
if ( jQuery.inArray( top.location.host, domains ) > -1 ) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href ;
}
```

It doesn't appear to be working, though. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `top` defined?

Comment: @tcigrand — It's a built-in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin security won't let you read the URL of a frame (including parent frames) on a different origin.

The only approach I can think of would be:

1. Wait for the frame content to load
2. Start a `setTimeout` that frame bursts by setting `top.location` after **x** seconds
3. Randomly generate a large number as a security code
4. Send a [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to `top` with that number in the message. Do this *in a loop* setting the `targetOrigin` to each of your allowed domains in turn.
5. In the `top` domain have an event listener waiting for the message with the security code that responds to it by immediately using `postMessage` to *send it back*. (NB: Because of the `targetOrigin`, only acceptable domains will be able to see the code).
6. Have an event listener in the framed page that waits for the code to come back. Check that it matches the one generated in step 3, then `clearTimeout` before the function does the frame burst.